How to escape $ sign and prevent consul-template to interpretate variable?
In consul-template for the next line:
template {
  destination = "local/script.sh"
  data        = <<-EOH
    cmd='bash -c \'source "${NOMAD_ALLOC_DIR}/creds.env"; backup\''
  EOH
}

I receive the error:
local/script.sh: line 22: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

I am looking for a way to generate literal string which will contain $NOMAD_ALLOC_DIR.

Escaping does not work. Here is the issue:
https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/issues/1968
